# How to use Swingworker do to run cod in a background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swingworker

I have a program that runs a given test and shows the results using GUI. I need from the program to not freeze when I run a long test.
I do all the tests in tester class that starts when we press the run button.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*; 

public class Tester {
private int setUp;
private int tearDown;
private int fail;
private int success;
private int exceptionFail;
private boolean hasSetup;
private boolean hasTeardown;
private boolean ready;
private String Name;
private Method\[\] methods;
private Class\<?\> test;
private String txtOutput;

    public Tester() {
        hasSetup = false;
        hasTeardown = false;
        ready = false;
        this.txtOutput = "";
    }
    
    
    public Boolean checkTest(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
        ready = false;
        if (isValidClass() && isATestClass(this.test)) {
            methods = this.test.getMethods();
            checkSetUpTearDown();
            ready = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    
    private void checkSetUpTearDown() {
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length;i++) {
            if ((methods[i].getName().compareTo("setUp") == 0) &&
                    (methods[i].getParameterCount() == 0)) {
                hasSetup = true;
                setUp = i;
            } else if ((methods[i].getName().compareTo("tearDown")) == 0 &&
                    (methods[i].getParameterCount() == 0)) {
                hasTeardown = true;
                tearDown = i;
    
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private boolean isValidClass() {
        try {
            boolean valid = false;
            test = Class.forName(Name);
            if (test.isInterface()) {
                txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("Class is Interface and cannot be a test\n");
                return false;
            }
            Constructor<?>[] constructors = test.getConstructors();
            for (Constructor con : constructors) {
                if (con.getParameterCount() == 0) {
    
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (false) {
                txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("Could not find a constructor that does not take any          arguments\n");
            }
            return true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("Could not find class: " + Name + "\n");
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("Could not find class: " + Name + " (Check spelling)\n\n");
        }
        return false;
    }
    

    private boolean isATestClass(Class<?> c) {
        Class<?>[] interfaces = c.getInterfaces();
        for (Class<?> anInterface : interfaces) {
            if (anInterface.getName().compareTo("se.umu.cs.unittest.TestClass") == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("Class does not implement the interface " +
                "se.umu.cs.unittest.TestClass.\n");
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public void runTests() {
        if (ready) {
            try {
                Object klass = test.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
                for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                    String methodName = methods[i].getName();
    
                    if (!methodName.startsWith("test") ||
                            (methods[i].getReturnType() != boolean.class) ||
                            (methods[i].getParameterCount() > 0)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    runMethod(klass, methodName, i);
                }
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("The class could not be " +
                        "initialized. This could be caused " +
                        "by the class being abstract" +
                        " or an array class or a primitive type.\n");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("Could not access the class or " +
                        "it's constructor.\n");
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("\n" + success + "tests succeeded\n" );
            txtOutput = txtOutput.concat(fail + "tests failed\n" );
            txtOutput = txtOutput.concat(exceptionFail + "tests failed because of an exception\n\n" );
    
            success = 0;
            fail = 0;
            exceptionFail = 0;
        }
    }
    
    
    private void runMethod(Object klass, String methodName, int methodIndex) {
        try{
            boolean methodReturn;
            if (hasSetup) {
                methods[setUp].invoke(klass);
            }
            methodReturn = (Boolean) methods[methodIndex].invoke(klass);
            if (methodReturn) {
                txtOutput = txtOutput.concat(methodName+": SUCCESS\n");
                success++;
            } else {
                txtOutput = txtOutput.concat(methodName+": FAIL\n");
                fail++;
            }
    
            if (hasTeardown) {
                methods[tearDown].invoke(klass);
            }
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            txtOutput = txtOutput.concat(methodName + ": FAIL Generated a " + e.getTargetException() + "\n");
            exceptionFail++;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            txtOutput = txtOutput.concat("Could not access the the method " + methodName + "\n");
        }
    }
    
    
    public String getTxtOutput() {
        String temp = txtOutput;
        txtOutput = "";
        return temp;
    }

}
```

Run button class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class RunButton implements ActionListener {

    private Tester tester;
    private UserInterface gui;


    public RunButton(UserInterface gui) {
        tester = new Tester();
        this.gui = gui;
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(tester.checkTest(gui.getText())){
                tester.runTests();

        }
        gui.setTxtOutputCont(tester.getTxtOutput());

    }




}
```

I know that I have to use Swingworker to run the tester class in background on another thread, but could not figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section. Pay particular attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) section.

Coding a `SwingWorker` is fairly straightforward.  You put the background code in the `doInBackground` method and any code to be executed when the background processing is done in the `done` method.

The only "trick" is specifying the return types of the `doInBackground` method and the `done` method.

Here's your modified `RunButton` class.  I didn't test the code, so if it doesn't work, edit your question to provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can compile in our IDE and test.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class RunButton implements ActionListener {

    private Tester tester;
    private UserInterface gui;

    public RunButton(UserInterface gui) {
        this.tester = new Tester();
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            public void doInBackground() {
                if (tester.checkTest(gui.getText())) {
                    tester.runTests();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void done() {
                gui.setTxtOutputCont(tester.getTxtOutput());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I had to change void doInBackground to Void and made it return null to be able to start the program. But the program doesn't run the tests any more.

Comment: Worked when I did this:                         
          `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            worker.execute();
    }`